# Is it good style to factor out the common root word of two (or more) prefixed compound words?

Tags: conjunctions, writing-style, hyphenation, compounds, disjunction

I see sometimes in conjunciton or disjunction, the common root of two or more compound words are factored out, for example, "super- and sub-script" (maybe bad example, but it suffices to describe the situation).  Is this good style?  To me, I would prefer "super-script and "sub-script".

Comment: "Good style" is an awfully subjective thing. It's grammatical; if you don't like it, don't do it.

Comment: Each has its merits. "*super- and sub-script*" essentially talks about the prefix, while "*super-script and "sub-script*" (better "*superscript and subscript*") discusses the terms as such. E.g.: "Codes for *super-* and *sub-script* are confusing to me" (which is super? which is sub?) vs. "The codes for *superscript* and *subscript* are distinct.

Comment: WritersSE could be a good place to ask about writing style.

Comment: @Kris: It's interesting that it really seems to make sense (but see Bill's offering) to hyphenate in the first case. There are very few examples of the hyphenated variants showing up in a Google search, and those are mainly for the contrastive super- and sub-script, as here. Another flexi-rule to put in the 100 000-page grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"[Superscript](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/superscript)" and "[subscript](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subscript)" are one word each without a hyphen in British and American English, so I'd advise against using the hyphen for them. And because they're both short words, there's almost nothing (4 characters) gained by splitting them. For longer compound words, using the hyphenated prefix for, say, "[**pre-** and **postrevolutionary**](http://snurl.com/26uf9qm)" focuses on **the time before & after** the revolution and makes that focus easier to understand, because they're both long words. "Good style" is case-by-case.